# referring correctly to files

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, cloud9

I have a problem referring to the right files in c9:

1. I want to refer to a picture.

this is my code so far: `<img src="pic1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">`. See my folder structure

[image: folder structure]

2. jquery

This is my code so far: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery.js">`. See my folder structure:

[image: folder strucutre]

Can you give me some advice on how to do it?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: once you have specified your `public` folder as the folder to serve static assets, you just need to keep your static assets (e.g images) in public folder and specify the path to the images relative to that `public` folder.

Answer (score -1):

You can drag your image into your search bar and it'll give you that information. 
Hope this helps in some way.

- Michael